# Getting individual sessions from Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've setup Google Analytics on a FAQ with a basic search feature. Users type their query, get a results list, and navigate in answers. Nothing fancy.

I'd like to get each individual session from GA, something like:

```
visitorId: 1234567890
date: 10/10/2010 12:34
query: "I have a problem"
results_visited: ...
```

I know that internally GA stores every hit on every page, but I don't know if it's possible to access this info through their API. I went through their documentation to no avail. Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Google doesn't allow you to access this directly from the API. The best solution I can think of is to parse the Google cookie at the time of the search and send the values you're looking for back to analytics as custom variables. Take a look at this: http://www.dannytalk.com/read-google-analytics-cookie-script/